# How to Programmatically Break on All Errors?

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to do is set a flag to go from this option:
[image]

To this option:

[image]

The reason for this is that I have error handlers throughout my code and whilst I'm debugging I want to be able to see what the errors are.

Setting the error flag off:

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

Will just take me back to the last place error handling was used, like two or three procedures before the one I'm working on.

The reasoning behind this is that I have a large codebase and I know there are several sections that I do not need to see what the errors are but I do once I get to a certain part of the processing (many hundreds of calls deep), it is at this point I want to turn on **Break on Unhandled Errors**.

Comment: You would have to use a lot of API jiggery-pokery to get to that setting and change it via code - in reality it would just be a hell of a lot simpler to go in and change it yourself while you need it.

Comment: There's a registry entry for it but I've never worked out how to get Excel to refresh that setting other than restarting it.

Comment: Thanks both, I thought it would be something along those lines and I have been doing as you suggest @MacroMan just changing the setting when I'm in the procedure

Comment: @Rory - I struggled with that for ages and I'm fairly confident that there is no other way to force Excel to read the reg values other than at startup :(

Comment: I must be missing something because `On Error GoTo 0` should cause errors to be raised when they happen if you are not inside some other error handler.

Comment: @MatthewD I am deep in the rabbit hole when trying to debug this and there are several error handlers behind the procedure I'm working on so even if i do use On Error GoTo 0 on the procedure I'm in it will take me back to the previous place where a On Error GoTo errHandler was used

Comment: You would have to post your code for the SO community to help you figure out the best way to deal with your situation.

Comment: You can change it fast by using Find->Replace -> Find What: `On Error Goto`  Replace With: `'On Error Goto`  Replace All or reverse in vba editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is old, but adding an answer for anyone that needs to do this in Excel VBA. I have an add-in that I developed for my company that uses the following technique:

1. Check for unwanted error trapping option using registry key (Break on All Errors in this example)
2. Change Registry Key if needed
3. Restart Excel (I let this part be manual but you could automate it depending on the circumstance)

```
Dim objShell As Object
Dim strErrOption As String
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next
strErrOption = objShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common\BreakOnAllErrors")
If strErrOption = 1 Or Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Break on All Errors Set or Reg Key DNE
    On Error GoTo 0
    objShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common\BreakOnAllErrors", 0
    MsgBox ("Please Restart Excel")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Note: Excel only reads the registry on open and only writes on close. This is why restarting the app is required.

- 0 is Break on Unhandled Errors
- 1 is Break on All Errors
- 2 is Break in Class Module

Comment: How is restarting Excel easier/better than manually changing the option (which doesn't require a restart)?

Comment: @41686d6564 It depends on the specific scenario. If this is for code you deploy to another person, I very much dislike requiring them to have to adjust their own settings. Additionally, this code can be ran on workbook_open and you could add code to automatically restart excel after (again as scenarios allow).

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say which VBA environment you are using.  In Access (and ***only*** in Access, as far as I know), there is a very useful method to programmatically modify the Error Trapping setting:

```
Application.SetOption("Error Trapping", 2) 
Debug.Print Application.GetOption("Error Trapping")
```

I've used this many times where I have error handling set up on an outer method, but I really want to see where the code is hitting an error somewhere far down in a call stack.  And just globally setting the Error Trapping to "Break on all errors" is a pain if you have expected, well-handled errors somewhere in your code, because it always stops on those! So, in Access, you can switch to "Break on All Errors" just in one section when you want to.

Comment: I was not aware of the .SetOption very userful! Thank you!

Comment: This would have been really useful but the question is tagged Excel.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, there isn't an easy way to do this other than manually change the setting in the options when you get to the section of the code you want to have a runtime error for rather than being taken to the last active error handler.

Comment: Thank you for researching the definitive answer on this. Saved me time from doing it myself.